# save state of changed database in android application

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I am working on an android app, in which the first page is a homepage. On clicking on any item on the homepage, the user can view details in that item. The details are taken from an sqlite database and can be accepted or rejected in the app by the user. On accept or reject by the user, the detail gets deleted from the list of details. But, on clicking back button from the details page, when the user reaches the homepage again, there occurs this problem that when the user clicks on the same item again, it shows all the details without saving state.

E.g. if my item1 has 10 details within it..i view all the 10 details in the details page..then accept 2..so total remain 8..but when i click back and reach the homepage and again click on item1, it shows all 10 again...and does not record the change which occured when 2 were accepted.

How can this be solved?

---

This is the code that we are working on:

```
package com.sql.nigel;


import java.util.ArrayList;

    public class listActivity extends ListActivity implements
    android.view.View.OnClickListener,OnItemClickListener{
    private ArrayList<listActivity2> m_orders = null;
    private OrderAdapter m_adapter;
    private Runnable viewOrders;
    private SQLiteDatabase database;
    private MySQLiteHelper dbHelper=new MySQLiteHelper(this);
    private String[] leave_Col =   {"Requester","LeaveType","No_of_Days","FromDate","ToDate"};
    private String[] Cart_Col = {"CartNo","Date","Description","TotalValue","TotalTax","BudgetValue","UniqueNo"};
    private String[] Time_Col = {"Name","Date","Project","Client","Tasks","FromDate","ToDate"};
    private String[] Travel_Col = {"Requester","Purpose","Location","Cost","Date","Description","FromDate","ToDate","Hotel","Taxi","AdditionalExp"};
    private String[] Invoice_Col = {"InvoiceNo","VendorName","Date","InvoiceValue","Date","VendorNo","PostingDate","FiscalYear","Pln_Group"};
    private String[] Purchase_Col = {"PONo","Date","Vendor","OrderValue","PurchasingOrg","ApprovedVendor","Requester","Notes","RelatedInfo","QualityScore"};
    String table_name;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.listactivity);

        database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        table_name=this.getIntent().getExtras().getString("activity");        

        Button backButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.back);
        backButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        Button selectButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.select);
        selectButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        /*    ImageView rightarrow = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.rightarrow);
        rightarrow.setOnClickListener(this);*/

        m_orders = new ArrayList<listActivity2>();
        this.m_adapter = new OrderAdapter(this, R.layout.listactivity2, m_orders);
        setListAdapter(this.m_adapter);


        ListView listView=(ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {
                if(table_name.compareTo("LeaveRequest")==0){
                    Intent intent = new Intent(listActivity.this, leavedetails.class); 
                    Bundle b = new Bundle(); //Create bundle
                    b.putInt("key",position); //Your id 
                    intent.putExtras(b); //Put your id to your next Intent 
                    startActivity(intent); //Call intent                    
               }else if(table_name.compareTo("Time")==0){
                   Intent intent = new Intent(listActivity.this, timedetails.class);
                   Bundle b = new Bundle(); //Create bundle
                    b.putInt("key",position); //Your id 
                    intent.putExtras(b); //Put your id to your next Intent 
                    startActivity(intent); //Call intent
                }else if(table_name.compareTo("ShoppingCart")==0){
                    Intent intent = new Intent(listActivity.this, cartdetails.class); 
                    Bundle b = new Bundle(); //Create bundle
                    b.putInt("key",position); //Your id 
                    intent.putExtras(b); //Put your id to your next Intent 
                    startActivity(intent); //Call intent
                }else if(table_name.compareTo("Invoice")==0){
                    Intent intent = new Intent(listActivity.this, invoicedetails.class);
                    Bundle b = new Bundle(); //Create bundle
                    b.putInt("key",position); //Your id 
                    intent.putExtras(b); //Put your id to your next Intent 
                    startActivity(intent); //Call intent
                }else if(table_name.compareTo("PurchaseOrder")==0){
                    Intent intent = new Intent(listActivity.this, purchasedetails.class); 
                    Bundle b = new Bundle(); //Create bundle
                    b.putInt("key",position); //Your id 
                    intent.putExtras(b); //Put your id to your next Intent 
                    startActivity(intent); //Call intent 
                }else if(table_name.compareTo("Travel")==0){
                    Intent intent = new Intent(listActivity.this, traveldetails.class);
                    Bundle b = new Bundle(); //Create bundle
                    b.putInt("key",position); //Your id 
                    intent.putExtras(b); //Put your id to your next Intent 
                    startActivity(intent); //Call intent

                }



            }
            });



        viewOrders = new Runnable(){
            public void run() {
                getOrders();
            }
        };

        Thread thread =  new Thread(null, viewOrders, "MagentoBackground");
        thread.start();

    }
    private Runnable returnRes = new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            if(m_orders != null && m_orders.size() > 0){
                m_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                for(int i=0;i<m_orders.size();i++)
                m_adapter.add(m_orders.get(i));
            }

            m_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    };
    private void getOrders(){
          try{
              m_orders = new ArrayList<listActivity2>();

              if(table_name.compareTo("LeaveRequest")==0){display_Leave();                            
              }else if(table_name.compareTo("Time")==0){display_Time(); 
              }else if(table_name.compareTo("ShoppingCart")==0){display_Cart(); 
              }else if(table_name.compareTo("Invoice")==0){display_Invoice(); 
              }else if(table_name.compareTo("PurchaseOrder")==0){display_Purchase(); 
              }else if(table_name.compareTo("Travel")==0){display_Travel(); 
              }

              Log.i("ARRAY", ""+ m_orders.size());
            } catch (Exception e) { 
              Log.e("BACKGROUND_PROC", e.getMessage());
            }
            runOnUiThread(returnRes);
            database.close();
        }
    public void display_Leave(){
          TextView heading=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.heading);
          heading.setText("Leave Request");
          Cursor c_L = database.query("LeaveRequest",leave_Col, null, null, null, null, null);
          c_L.moveToFirst();        
          while (!c_L.isAfterLast()) {              
          listActivity2 o1 = new listActivity2();             
          o1.setOrdertext1(""+c_L.getString(0));
          o1.setOrdertext2(""+c_L.getString(2)+" days");
          o1.setOrdertext3(""+c_L.getString(1)+" ");
          o1.setOrdertext4(""+c_L.getString(3)+" to "+c_L.getString(4));                        
          m_orders.add(o1);
          c_L.moveToNext();              
          } c_L.close();            
      }
    public void display_Time(){
      TextView heading=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.heading);
      heading.setText("Time Booking");
      Cursor c_L = database.query("Time",Time_Col, null, null, null, null, null);
          c_L.moveToFirst();        
          while (!c_L.isAfterLast()) {              
          listActivity2 o1 = new listActivity2();             
        o1.setOrdertext1(""+c_L.getString(0));
        o1.setOrdertext2(""+c_L.getString(3));
        o1.setOrdertext3(""+c_L.getString(2)+" ");
        o1.setOrdertext4(""+c_L.getString(1));                          
        m_orders.add(o1);
        c_L.moveToNext();              
          } c_L.close();            
    }
    public void display_Cart(){
          TextView heading=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.heading);
          heading.setText("Shopping Cart");
          Cursor c_L = database.query("ShoppingCart",Cart_Col, null, null, null, null, null);
          c_L.moveToFirst();        
          while (!c_L.isAfterLast()) {              
          listActivity2 o1 = new listActivity2();             
          o1.setOrdertext1(""+c_L.getString(0));
          o1.setOrdertext2("");
          o1.setOrdertext3(""+c_L.getString(2)+" ");
          o1.setOrdertext4(""+c_L.getString(1));                        
          m_orders.add(o1);
          c_L.moveToNext();              
          } c_L.close();            
      }
    public void display_Invoice(){
          TextView heading=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.heading);
          heading.setText("Invoice Approval");
          Cursor c_L = database.query("Invoice",Invoice_Col, null, null, null, null, null);
          c_L.moveToFirst();        
          while (!c_L.isAfterLast()) {              
          listActivity2 o1 = new listActivity2();             
          o1.setOrdertext1(""+c_L.getString(1));
          o1.setOrdertext2("");
          o1.setOrdertext3(""+c_L.getString(0)+" ");
          o1.setOrdertext4(""+c_L.getString(2));                        
          m_orders.add(o1);
          c_L.moveToNext();              
          } c_L.close();            
      }
    public void display_Purchase(){
      TextView heading=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.heading);
      heading.setText("Purchase Order");
      Cursor c_L = database.query("PurchaseOrder",Purchase_Col, null, null, null, null, null);
          c_L.moveToFirst();        
          while (!c_L.isAfterLast()) {              
          listActivity2 o1 = new listActivity2();             
        o1.setOrdertext1(""+c_L.getString(0));
        o1.setOrdertext2(""+c_L.getString(3));
        o1.setOrdertext3(""+c_L.getString(2)+" ");
        o1.setOrdertext4(""+c_L.getString(1));                          
        m_orders.add(o1);
        c_L.moveToNext();              
          } c_L.close();            
    }
    public void display_Travel(){
          TextView heading=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.heading);
          heading.setText("Travel Approval");
          Cursor c_L = database.query("Travel",Travel_Col, null, null, null, null, null);
          c_L.moveToFirst();        
          while (!c_L.isAfterLast()) {              
          listActivity2 o1 = new listActivity2();             
          o1.setOrdertext1(""+c_L.getString(1));
          o1.setOrdertext2(""+c_L.getString(3));
          o1.setOrdertext3(""+c_L.getString(2)+" ");
          o1.setOrdertext4(""+c_L.getString(4));                        
          m_orders.add(o1);
          c_L.moveToNext();              
          } c_L.close();            
      }
    private class OrderAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<listActivity2> {

        private ArrayList<listActivity2> items;

        public OrderAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<listActivity2> items) {
                super(context, textViewResourceId, items);
                this.items = items;
        }
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                View v = convertView;
                if (v == null) {
                    LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                    v = vi.inflate(R.layout.listactivity2, null);
                }
                listActivity2 o = items.get(position);
                if (o != null) {
                        TextView t1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textList1);
                        TextView t2 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textList2);
                        TextView t3 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textList3);
                        TextView t4 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textList4);
                        if (t1 != null) {
                              t1.setText(o.getOrdertext1());           
                        }
                        if(t2 != null){
                              t2.setText(o.getOrdertext2());
                        }
                        if(t3 != null){
                              t3.setText(o.getOrdertext3());
                        }
                        if(t4 != null){
                              t4.setText(o.getOrdertext4());
                        }
                }
                return v;
        }
}

    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch(v.getId())
        {
        case R.id.back:
            Intent backIntent = new Intent(listActivity.this, SqlTwoActivity.class); 

            startActivity(backIntent);                  
            break;

        case R.id.select:
            Intent selectIntent = new Intent(listActivity.this, checkappear.class);
            selectIntent.putExtra("checkappear", table_name);
            startActivity(selectIntent);                    
            break;  
        /*  
        case R.id.rightarrow:
            Intent rightarrow = new Intent(listActivity.this, listActivity.class);
            startActivity(rightarrow);                  
            break;*/        
        }
    }
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

Comment: It's hard to see the problem without any code, could you maybe post some?

Comment: I understand but the problem is there are many xmls and java files for the same...so it becomes difficult to post here since theyr huge too..:/ I could elaborate on the problem and any help will be appreciated

Comment: post the points where you make SQLite calls. What happens when you click accept on the 2 items? Can you show logs that you actually DO SQlite calls. If that's the case maybe you REinitiallize something after you hit back button. Maybe you use the old object instance that has all 10 details, not a new one...could be lots of things without seeing your code.

Comment: I'm guessing both the Homepage and the Details page are two separate Activities? How about posting the `onCreate()` of the Details page and maybe the Intent call in the Homepage as well as the stuff @hovanessyan said?

Comment: there is a homepage....on the homepage suppose there are 6 icons....on clicking one icon, it gives details within that icon...i.e. it moves from homepage to details page....on details page i hav suppose 10 details in list form...i can approve or reject any...so say i approve 2..then they get deleted from the list...but when i go back to the homepage and again click on the same icon, all details are displayed including the accepted one...which shouldnt happen

Comment: surely i wil post that in a few

Answer (score 0):

Hard to find database calls in your code. Some general guidelines:

First you need to encapsulate all calls to the Database in separate threads.
Always close your cursors and DB connection after you're finished. 
Best would be to use [AsyncTask](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidPerformance/article.html). Check out some tutorials for using SQLite with AsyncTask - it will handle the separate Thread automatically for you.

Second - read about the [Activity Stack](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/tasks-and-back-stack.html), so that what @Peter tells you makes sense.